# PHP string remove everything but center numbers?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string "Mod. 816-10 025" and I want to remove everything but the 816-10.

Conditions:

- The number in the center will always be ###-##
- It may not be 3 numbers - 2 numbers but it will always be space numbers dash numbers space

Can someone help me? I've tried like 5 different regex but no success.

Comment: You say "but it will always be space numbers dash numbers space". How exactly are you so sure of this? Got a real world example, a list perhaps?

Comment: Its just amazing how responders jump through hoops with no questions, or ..

Comment: Using native functions won over regex... geez

Comment: Tags should have been php regex native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the conditions always remain, there is no need for RegEx:

```
$string = explode(" ","Mod. 816-10 025");
$number = $string[1];
```

**Note:** Using php native functions will usually be faster than the powerful RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "Mod. 816-10 025";
echo preg_replace('~.+ (\d+-\d+) .+~', '\1', $text);
// prints: 816-10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
# ...
$pattern = '/\d+-\d+/';
$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);
```

Now `$matches[0]` will have you NUM-NUM string. If you want to limit the size of the numbers (if it were between 2 and 3 digits all the time, the pattern could be something like `/\d{2,3}-\d{2,3}/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = "Mod. 816-10 025";
$bar = explode(" ", $foo);
$result = $bar[1];
```

all these answers could be right, its just a matter of what exactly you where looking for.

Answer (score 0):

People are posting about preg_replace answers but none of them are taking care of any whitepace except an space. If you prefer `preg_replace()` to `preg_match()`, I'd rather use

```
preg_replace('/.*\s+(\d+-\d+)\s+.*/', '$1', $input);
```